# Pandas Dataframe Plot

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a time series data. The dataframe looks like this

```
[1]:Index  ship_date  cost_amount 
    0       1/8/2010  34276 
    1       1/8/2010  12375 
    2       1/8/2011  12343 
    3       2/9/2011  15435

[2]: df1.plot(figsize(20,5))
```

I am trying to plot the data but for some reason plot doesn't have x-axis in ascending order. How do I get the plot with date ascending or descending order ?
[image: Plot without dates in order]

Comment: Its in no order I guess.. If you see the first point in x is 2011 then 2010 and after some time it is 2010 again.

Comment: Is that the exact code you've used to produce that graph? As it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Looks like the dates in that dataframe are strings, not dates, at a quess...  The labels are in lexicographically ascending order...

Comment: Try converting the `ship_date` column to datetime: `df1['ship_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ship_date'])`

Comment: Oopss.. Sorry.. I forgot to write one more line. Since the data had duplicate dates, I grouped them like this `df1 = df1.groupby('Ship Date').sum()` which makes Ship date the index for df1

Comment: Changing to datetime worked. Thanks @EdChum :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (as spotted by @ J Richard Snape) is that your dates are in fact strings so it's ordered lexicographically.

You should convert to datetime dtype:

```
df1['Ship_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Ship_date'])
```

After which it should maintain the expected order.